# React Private Route with hooks in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, routes

I'm building an application. The user has to login to nagivate to dashboard or other pages. I have defined the routes in App.tsx file

```
const App = () => {

  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState<IState["authenticated"]>(false)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element = {<LogIn setAuthenticated={setAuthenticated}/>} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={authenticated} redirectPath={"/"} {...<Dashboard/>}/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is a general PrivateRoute component

```
import { Navigate, Route} from 'react-router';

interface IProtectedRoute {
    isAuthenticated: boolean,
    redirectPath: string,
}

const PrivateRoute = ({isAuthenticated, redirectPath, ...routeProps}: IProtectedRoute) => {

    console.log("Authenticated ", isAuthenticated)
        return(
            isAuthenticated ?
        <Route {...routeProps}/>
        : <Navigate to={redirectPath} />
        )
    

};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

After login the redirect to dashboard doesn't work, the error I get is the following

> "Error: A Route is only ever to be used as the child of Routes
> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your Route in a Routes"

I am confused about writing a general PrivateRoute component. I want to reuse it depending on what pages the user wants to access after login. I am confused with types. What kind of type should the functional component that PrivateRoute receives and how it should handle props and also what should it return in order to be rendered correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to wrap your route like that?
    <Routes>
      <Route {...routeProps} />
    </Routes>

Comment: Yes, it's even worse